# How do I rewrite a repetitive jquery code

Tags: javascript, loops

How could I rewrite this jquery code to compact it in a more elegant form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="table_exist"]').click(function(){
        if($('input[name="table_name"]').val()=='users' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="table_name"]').val('');
        }
        else if($('input[name="table_name"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="table_name"]').val('user');
        }

        if($('input[name="user_id"]').val()=='user_id' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_id"]').val('');
        }
        else if($('input[name="user_id"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_id"]').val('user_id');
        }

        if($('input[name="user_name"]').val()=='user_name' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_name"]').val('');
        }
        else if($('input[name="user_name"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_name"]').val('user_name');
        }

        if($('input[name="user_email"]').val()=='user_email' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_email"]').val('');
        }
        else if($('input[name="user_email"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_email"]').val('user_email');
        }

        if($('input[name="user_pass"]').val()=='user_pass' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_pass"]').val('');
        }
        else if($('input[name="user_pass"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="user_pass"]').val('user_pass');
        }

        if($('input[name="joining_date"]').val()=='joining_date' && $('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="joining_date"]').val('');
        }
        else if($('input[name="joining_date"]').val()=='' && !$('input[name="table_exist"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[name="joining_date"]').val('joining_date');
        }
    });
});
```

The whole process is to identify if the fields have the default values when a checkbox is unchecked. If the state is changed to checked then empty all fields to input custom information/values. If unchecked again it returns the initial values.

Comment: If the current version works properly, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better address to improve your code.

Comment: I solved it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210361/jquery-code-to-detect-whether-form-fields-have-the-default-value-when-a-checkbox/210379#210379 for anyone who is curious!